# MYSQL - COUNT distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two data tables, you can find them attached.

I wanted to obtain the:

- Code
- Name of the subjects
- Number of non evaluable activities

***But only of the subjects that have 4 or more non evaluable activities***...

This is the code I have so far but the "Name" I get is not what I want...

And this is what I was hoping for (attached)

I tried other things and I get the correct name but not what I want..

Any help? Thanks!

**Table 1**

[image: Table 1]

**Table 2**

[image: Table 2]

**My code**

[image: My code]

**Result I want**

[image: Result I want]

**Other wrong code**

[image: Other wrong code]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text, put it right in the question, possibly in your case supplemented by an sql fiddle (or equivalent) you set up for us.

Comment: don't post link  ... post text

Comment: Ok my bad, i needed more rep to post the images so it was easier for you guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing from your first query is the join criteria. Your code simply says `... FROM table1 JOIN table2 GROUP BY...` A join without a join condition will create a cartesian join ( all records from table1 will be paired with all records from table2). Just remove the group by and the count from your query to see what I mean with this.

Simply add the join condition (subject_id seems to be the common field between the two table):

```
... FROM table1 JOIN table2 on table1.subject_id=table2.subject_id GROUP BY...
```

Pls replce table1 and table2 with your respective table names.

Comment: Just one more question if you are up for it :)

If I wanted from the same tables to obtain name and number of non eval activities that have 'Castellano in language and have => 4 non eval act how would it be?

I tried:
SELECT subject.name as 'Subject', COUNT(act_id)
FROM subject JOIN nonevaluableactivity on subject.subject_id=nonevaluableactivity.subject_id
WHERE COUNT(act_id) >= 4, language = 'Castellano'

But its not working

Comment: If you have a new question, then pls post it as a new question, not as a comment to an answer. If my answer helped you to resolve your question, then pls accept it as a solution.

Comment: yes thank you man, I just wanted to have some extra help and not wait 90min again hhaha

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your second query : it’s a good ideas to use an aggregated query with a « HAVING BY » clause, however the way you JOIN tables is not ok, as it is it results in a cartesian product.

Try :

```
SELECT
    s.subject_id,
    s.name,
    COUNT(distinct n.act_id)
FROM 
    subject as s
    INNER JOIN nonevaluableactivity as n
        ON n.subject_id = s.subject_id
GROUP BY
    s.subject_id,
    s.name
HAVING
    COUNT(distinct n.act_id) >= 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me with the extra question as well! :)